# Replace sub-sub-arrays in a (m, n, 2)-shaped 3D numpy array using a dictionary as map

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `input_array` of shape `(m, n, 2)` and a dictionary `mapping` (`Dict[Tuple[int, int], float]`). I like to create a new `(m, n)` `output_array` by replacing the inner most arrays in the `input_array` based on the `mapping` dictionary.

**Example:**

```
input_array = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 7]], [[1, 2], [4, 5]]])
mapping = {(1, 2): 0.7, (3, 7): 0.8, (4, 5): 0.9, (2, 4): 0.3}
---
output_array = np.array([[0.7, 0.8], [0.7, 0.9]])
```

**Attempt:**

```
import time
import numpy as np

def map_values(input_array, mapping):
    output_array = np.empty(input_array.shape[:2], dtype=float)

    tic = time.time()
    for key in np.unique(input_array.reshape(-1, 2), axis=0):
        value = mapping[tuple(key)]
        
        mask = np.all(input_array == key, axis=-1)
        indices = np.where(mask)
        output_array[indices[0], indices[1]] = value
    toc = time.time()
    print(f'mapping loop took {toc-tic:.4f} seconds')

    return output_array
```

Is there a way to make the looping and replacement of arrays faster?

Comment: Is the map always going to cover every pair in the input? (Every pair always going to be replaced?)

Comment: @MatBailie yes. map may even have additional tuples not present in the input. number of unique tuples in the input <= tuples (key) in the map. And, yes, every pair in input is going to be replaced.

Comment: A dict requires some sort of loop(s).  Each key has to be accessed individually; there's no special numpy access to a dict.  `dict.items()` (`values`) can convert the dict to a list.

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/4a032ca993

Comment: On https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy-unique there is a sample how to "Reconstruct the input array from the unique values and inverse". If you use this and replace the array of unique values by the mapped values before reconstruction, it may be faster than building a mask for each key.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple loop:

```
out = (np.array([mapping[l] for l in
                 map(tuple, input_array.reshape(-1, 2))])
         .reshape(input_array.shape[:-1])
      )
```

Or, if you expect many duplicated values, you could reduce the mapping step to the unique values, although the bottleneck being `np.unique` this might not be much faster if `n` is large:

```
tmp, idx = np.unique(input_array.reshape(-1, 2),
                     return_inverse=True, axis=0)

out = (np.array([mapping[tuple(l)] for l in tmp])[idx]
         .reshape(input_array.shape[:-1])
      )
```

Output:

```
array([[0.7, 0.8],
       [0.7, 0.9]])
```

###### timings

On (2, 2, 2):

```
# original
86 µs ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# this answer: simple loop
7.08 µs ± 811 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# this answer: only mapping unique values
60.7 µs ± 1.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

On (200, 200, 2):

```
# original
33.7 ms ± 4.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# this answer: simple loop
45.7 ms ± 3.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# this answer: only mapping unique values
30 ms ± 854 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For large `m` (or `n`) (2000, 2, 2):

```
# original
2.78 ms ± 366 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# this answer: simple loop
4.54 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# this answer: only mapping unique values
2.3 ms ± 6.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For large `m` and `n` (e.g. (2000, 2000, 2)):

```
# original
4.5 s ± 67.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# this answer: simple loop
4.29 s ± 35.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# this answer: simple loop
4.31 s ± 108 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As noted by @MatBailie, the simple loop can be further improved using `np.fromiter`:

```
N = input_array.shape[-1]
out = (np.fromiter((mapping[l] for l in
                   map(tuple, input_array.reshape(-1, N))),
                   float, count=input_array.size//N)
         .reshape(input_array.shape[:-1])
      )
```

Comment: As I understand it, the simple version would benefit from using `np.fromiter((comprehension, float, count=input_array.size>>1)`?

Comment: @MatBailie it's indeed slightly faster (a few percent), but not a game changer ;)

Comment: Could also use `map(mapping.get, map(tuple, ...))`